# I want to use VBA to open a list of website URL's which I have listed in excel and return a value from a specific object

Tags: html, vba

Below is an example of the pages I want to open automatically. There are about 2K in total. I have a list of all the address' in an excel document.

```
https://www.nmlsconsumeraccess.org/EntityDetails.aspx/COMPANY/238008
https://www.nmlsconsumeraccess.org/EntityDetails.aspx/COMPANY/238046
https://www.nmlsconsumeraccess.org/EntityDetails.aspx/COMPANY/238066
```

I would like to return the value for the object ID Company. The value for company is different for each ID at the end of the URL. I would like the results to be saved in an excel spreadsheet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to extract the id from the end of the url?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the expected result for each of the above and some sample code to show what you have tried so far as well as an explanation of what isn't working. Otherwise, this reads like a request for work.